# Call function in Golang

Tags: go

I have a function like this:

```
var flagvar int
func init() {
    flag.IntVar(&flagvar, "flagname", 1234, "help message for flagname")
}
```

I want to call it in `func main()`:

```
func main(){
  init()
}
```

But it does not work and told me `init()` is not defined.
What's the problem?

Comment: Just rename your init function

Comment: It's not needed to call the `init` function in your case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `init` function is a special function in Golang. It is executed the first time the file is loaded, so you never have to call it directly.

From the official documentation:

> Finally, each source file can define its own niladic init function to set up whatever state is required. (Actually each file can have multiple init functions.) And finally means finally: init is called after all the variable declarations in the package have evaluated their initializers, and those are evaluated only after all the imported packages have been initialized.